# Increase or decrease const byte value inside the code with a push button

Tags: button, constants

I'm kind of new in the Arduino world. I decided to make a self learning project with an Arduino where it controls a conveyor that simply moves from right to left and back again. There is a start and stop button. On each end of the conveyor are inductive sensors to stop the motor when it reaches the end position. After a delay, the conveyer starts again the opposite direction. Inside the code I have a cycle counter that stops the conveyer after a certain number of cycles.
Now my question is, how could I change the value of the cycle counter using two push buttons. One to increase the other to decrease.

If there is somebody who could help I would appreciate.
Thanks already

```
const byte sensorLinksEnd  =  2;
const byte sensorRechtsEnd =  3;
const byte startPin        =  4;
const byte stopPin         =  5;
const byte relaisLinks     =  6;
const byte relaisRechts    =  7;

enum {relaisAn, relaisAus};
enum {warten, on, rechts, haltrechts, links, haltlinks, off};
byte schritt = warten;
byte zyklus = 20; //cycles
const byte maxzyklus = 20; //max cycles

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(F("Start...."));
  pinMode(sensorLinksEnd, INPUT);
  pinMode(sensorRechtsEnd, INPUT);
  pinMode(startPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(stopPin,  INPUT);
  pinMode(relaisLinks, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(relaisLinks, relaisAus);
  pinMode(relaisRechts, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(relaisRechts, relaisAus);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  schrittkette();
}

void schrittkette()
{
  static unsigned long lastmillis;
  const unsigned long pauseZeit = 5000; // in ms
  if (digitalRead(stopPin))
  {
    schritt = off;
  }
  switch (schritt)
  {
    case warten:
      if (digitalRead(startPin))
      {
        zyklus = 0;
        schritt = on;
      }
      digitalWrite(relaisRechts, relaisAus);
      digitalWrite(relaisLinks, relaisAus);
      break;
    case on:
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
      schritt = rechts;
      break;
    case rechts:
      digitalWrite(relaisRechts, relaisAn);
      if (digitalRead(sensorRechtsEnd))
      {
        digitalWrite(relaisRechts, relaisAus);
        schritt = haltrechts;
        lastmillis = millis();
      }
      break;
    case haltrechts:
      digitalWrite(relaisRechts, relaisAus);
      digitalWrite(relaisLinks, relaisAus);
      if (millis() - lastmillis > pauseZeit)
      {
        schritt = links;
      }
      break;
    case links:
      digitalWrite(relaisRechts, relaisAus);
      digitalWrite(relaisLinks, relaisAn);
      if (digitalRead(sensorLinksEnd))
      {
        digitalWrite(relaisLinks, relaisAus);
        schritt = haltlinks;
        lastmillis = millis();
      }
      break;
    case haltlinks:
      digitalWrite(relaisRechts, relaisAus);
      digitalWrite(relaisLinks, relaisAus);
      if (millis() - lastmillis > pauseZeit)
      {
        if (zyklus == maxzyklus)
        {
          schritt = off;
        }
        else
        {
          zyklus++; 
          schritt = rechts;
        }
      }
      break;
    case off:
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
      schritt = warten;
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? With what exactly do you have problems? And please include your code in your question (not in the comments please)

Comment: The wording in your question's subject makes me wonder if you've read [what const does](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/variable-scope-qualifiers/const/).

Comment: @timemage thanks for the reply. Ok the const is only read-only. What woul be a alternative for that? How i can post here my complete Code? Sorry it´s the first time here

Comment: I put the complete Code in the first question

Comment: The alternative would be to not use the `const` keyword there. If it shouldn't be constant, then don't use the `const` keyword. For your whole question: You could divide that up into reading buttons and into changing variables. With which do you have problems exactly and what have you tried so far? Have you googled for tutorials on how to read buttons?

Comment: @chrisl  I know now that I can't use const. I would need I think a unsigned int or better a unsigned long. I want to be able to change a big number. Something around 60000 cycles.  It was over the tutorials that I was able to make my start and stop buttons. But unfortunately to change a variable like I want I didn't found until now nothing that I could understand. I'm a complete beginner in c++ coding. What I have until now is taking out from examples or asking for some tips. If you know a tutorial who would help for this particular situation, I would appreciate your help

Comment: @CarlosCosta is it `maxzyklus` that you wish to use as your cycle counter variable?

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody. I found a solution.

Comment: How I can put on a easy way here my Code to show?

Comment: @CarlosCosta If you have found a solution to your problem, you can write an own answer to your question and accept that as correct. Glad you found a solution and are willing to share it. +1

Answer (score 1):

The `const` keyword tells the C/C++ compiler that the variable is a constant and cannot be changed in your code anymore.

Simply remove `const` and you can modify `maxzyklus` by using 2 digital inputs.

```
byte maxzyklus = 20; //max cycles
```